# Picking the last value when there are multiple incorrect datapoints in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a data cleaning question. The data collection happened three times and sometimes the data entry was incorrect. Therefore, if the students had their data collected more than one time, the last data point needs to be copied over.

Here is my dataset looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3, 4),
                 text = c("female","male","male", "female","female","female", "male","female","female", "male"),
                 time = c("first","second","third", "first","second","third", "first","second","third", "first"))
    
> df
   id   text   time
1   1 female  first
2   1   male second
3   1   male  third
4   2 female  first
5   2 female second
6   2 female  third
7   3   male  first
8   3 female second
9   3 female  third
10  4   male  first
```

So first and third students have the different gender information because of the wrong input. Need the last time (third) point data copied over the rest.

The desired output would be

```
> df1
   id   text   time
1   1   male  first
2   1   male second
3   1   male  third
4   2 female  first
5   2 female second
6   2 female  third
7   3 female  first
8   3 female second
9   3 female  third
10  4   male  first
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(text = last(text)) %>% ungroup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `last` to return the last value of 'text' which gets `recycled` to update the column in `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(text = last(text)) %>% 
   ungroup
```

---

If we want the second or third value, use `nth` and modify the `n` to take the `min`inum value of 2 or the group size `n()` (when there are less than 2 elements per group)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(text = nth(text, min(c(2, n()))))
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I would want to use the "second" data point? How can I modify this?

Comment: @amisos55 you can use `nth(text, 2)`, but note that for the 'id' 4, there is no 2nd value as group size is 1, thus it returns NA

Comment: @amisos55 if you want to automatically take the last value if the group size is 1 and for others it is second, `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(text = nth(text, min(c(2, n()))))`

Comment: yes,  I am aware of that. Is there a way to specify the data point as `second` rather than `nth(text, 2)`?

Comment: @amisos55 what is the issue with `nth`, it does select based on index.  There is no `second` function I am aware of (for this case).  Besides `nth` is more general

Comment: sometime the order might have been different but I will order the datafirst. then your solution shoudl cover eveything. thanks1

Comment: I see, `nth()` is the function and `2` show the second order. gotcha.

Comment: @amisos55 the `min(c(2, n())` should take care of those cases